# Add a class or id when changing the language magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, template, magento2.3, multi-language, language-switcher

pls help me! How to Add a class or id to html or body when changing the language magento 2

Answer (score 1):

Add the store code class at body using the observer

1.first you have to create a custom module

2.you have to create the observer for **layout_load_before** at Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/events.xml and write down the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="cutom_bodystoreclass" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\BodyStoreClass" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2.Now create the folder Plugin and create the file BodyStoreClass.php in your Modulenae folder and write down the below code

```
<?php
namespace VoolaTech\StoreClass\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
class BodyStoreClas implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $config;
    protected $storeManager;
    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $storeCode = $store->getCode();
        $websiteCode = $store->getWebsite()->getCode();
        $this->config->addBodyClass($storeCode);
        $this->config->addBodyClass($websiteCode);
    }
}
```

3.Now remove the folder genarated and var using command line

```
rm rf generated/ var
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at source code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
[... stuff ...]
```

The source code you are looking for is located in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`.

To change this behavior copy the above file to your current theme directory.

`app/design/frontend/YOURVENDORNAME/YOURTHEME/Magento_Theme/templates/root.phtml`

Then do something like this

```
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$dynamicVariable     = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
?>
<html <?= $htmlAttributes ?> class="<?= $dynamicVariable; ?>">
```

It's a simple example but that should be enough to get you started.

And although I've used the object manager you could do a neater job with helper or ViewModel if using 2.3.